# wireshark is not capturing packets

Tags: networking, wireshark

I've executed Wireshark and I tried to capture packets.

I got the following error which shows up after clicking "start capturing":

[image: error message]

Comment: Could you please post text files, dialogue messages, and program output listings as text, not as images? To achieve the latter two you can either 1) select, copy & paste the dialogue text or terminal content or 2) [save the program output to a file](//askubuntu.com/q/420981/175814) and use that. Longer listings (the editor will tell you what's too long) should be uploaded to a [pastie service](https://paste.ubuntu.com/) and linked to in the question. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

The error says:

> You don't have permissions to capture on that device

`wireshark` require `root` access in order to capture data on a network device, as it uses [Promiscuous mode](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Promiscuous_mode)

Executing wireshark using `sudo` should solve the problem (by execution the program as `root`)

```
sudo wireshark
```

Comment: This is not the best solution, as wireshark should not be run with root rights. To allow users to run wireshark, run `sudo dpkg-reconfigure wireshark-common`, answer`Yes` and add the user to group `wireshark` (see https://ask.wireshark.org/questions/7976/wireshark-setup-linux-for-nonroot-user).

Comment: I agree that it is not the best solution, but it is the simplest solution. I saw the wireshark page before I post my answer, and had internal debate if I should include it as a link.... Do you think that I should add it to my answer?